# How can i separately crawl this code?

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-crawler

I have been developing a web-crawler using python 3.6 at this moment, and just got a trouble with this code. I need to separately collect the text data from each "dd". I can tell first "dd" by using "class_=first" code. But I am confused with how to separately collect the second "dd" and third "dd" without "class".

Also, I would like to collect the text data from the second "dd" separately(e.g. 2012 | April).

Please give me some advice.

Thanks.

(Code)

```
<dd class="first">
    <span class="t">Plate Number</span>
    <span class="s">43-3180</span>
</dd>
<dd>
    <span class="t">Year</span> 
    <span class="s"><em class="red">2012&nbsp;Apr.</em></span>
</dd>
<dd>
    <span class="t">Mileage</span>
    <span class="s"><em class="red">60,000 km</em></span>
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<dd class="first">
    <span class="t">Plate Number</span>
    <span class="s">43-3180</span>
</dd>
<dd>
    <span class="t">Year</span>
    <span class="s"><em class="red">2012&nbsp;Apr.</em></span>
</dd>
<dd>
    <span class="t">Mileage</span>
    <span class="s"><em class="red">60,000 km</em></span>
</dd>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

dds = soup.find_all('dd')

for dd in dds:
    span_t = dd.find_all('span', {'class': 't'})[0]
    span_s = dd.find_all('span', {'class': 's'})[0]
    print(span_t.text)
    print(span_s.text)

    >> Plate Number
       43-3180
       Year
       2012 Apr.
       Mileage
       60,000 km
```